# Your pets sleeping next to you

Tags: sentence-construction, idioms, past-tense, prepositional-phrases

I have a question. I was speaking with someone and I wanted to tell them that I like to share bed with my pets. How can I speak about this in the past without making mistakes. Can I say my cat slept with or next to me a few nights ago..or does it have a different meaning or is a mistake to say it this way?

I am really stuck. I would appreciate an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think either one ("I slept with my pets" or "I slept next to my pets") is fine. I'll warn you that with humans, "sleep with" typically has a sexual meaning, but with pets, only people with very dirty minds will think of that possibility.

Comment: I'd probably choose to say "my cat slept in my bed [with me]" to avoid unintended double entendres.

Comment: I know what you are talking about. But some people do have very dirty minds. Anyway I wanted to be sure I'm saying the right thing. Thank you very much, I really appreciate!!

Answer (score 1):

More usually (and guaranteed safer as well!) In English - "My cat usually sleeps on my bed", "My cat sleeps next to me/near me on the bed", or "I let the cat sleep on the bed".

It's more usual to hear it this way round (although perfectly correct the other way as well) because its word order reflects the fact that the cat is choosing where the cat sleeps, not the human choosing where the cat sleeps, and the human is allowing it. So the cat is an active subject and the sentence starting "the cat sleeps" reflects this.